# Change width on child element when parent has overflow set to hidden

Tags: css

I have a collapsible panel that was designed in a way that the children (green) are wider than their parent (red). Because there children have borders and there are icons added via ::before and ::after, when the whole panel collapses it borders on the children stay large until the animation on the parent is completed.

I can avoid these annoying lines from staying on the screen if I change the parent's overflow to hidden, unfortunately doing this clips the styling on the children and we don't get to see the elements the way they were intended.

Is there a way to keep the parent with overflow hidden and allow the children to have a width that exceeds the width of the parent? any tricks?

[image: container with overflow set to hidden]

Comment: But that is what `overflow: hidden` does (and clip the childen if they exceed their parent), so what is it you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you provide your html/CSS

Comment: Thank you guys I will add a fiddle now that I have it fixed and working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are collapsing it horizontally and the problem is that the elements keep adjusting to the new width until the width stops transitioning to the new value.

If that is correct, you might need to change from using `width` to collapse the panel to `transform: scaleX(0);`. It should take care of child elements re-rendering and elements being visible after the width is zero.

Comment: Thank you Nikhil you were right on the money, in order for the children style to be invisible until the animation on the parent completes, I need to use transform instead of transition on the parent. great tip. thanks!